# Unzipper skipper folders inside zip file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to unzip a file that includes files and folders , but i can only see 
 one file got extracted and rest of the files and folders are missing after unzipping it. I'm using `unzipper` library.

Here is the code snippet:

```
  var writeStream = fstream.Writer(outputPath);

readStream
  .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
  .pipe(writeStream)
```

**Update** 
After looking at closely, it looks like only last file from zip exists in the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this

```
const unzipper =require('unzipper');
const fs =require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('./files.zip')
  .pipe(unzipper.Extract({path:'output/path'}))
```

> [reference](https://github.com/ZJONSSON/node-unzipper#extract-to-a-directory)

Comment: yes i tried that .  It's doing the same (skipping folders)

Comment: are the folders are zipped as well?

Comment: check `unzipper` module version, make sure you are on the latest stable version